# Base class template instantiation depending on derived class constructor argument type

Tags: c++, templates

In the following, shouldn't base class constructor be generated by the compiler based on derived class constructor argument type?

```
template <class T>
class foo
{
int a;
public:
    foo(T a){}
    // When I convert the constructor to a function template, it works fine.
    // template <typename T> foo(T a){}
};

class bar : public foo<class T>
{
public:
    bar(int a):foo(a){}
};

int main(void)
{
    bar obj(10);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

> error C2664: 'foo::foo(T)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'T'

I understand the error, but why is that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax in `class bar : public foo<class T>` is incorrect.

- Either `bar` depends on a template parameter `T` and `bar` should be a template :

  ```
  template<class T>
  class bar : public foo<T>
  {
  public:
      bar(int a):foo(a){}
  };


  int main()
  {
      bar<int> obj(10);
  }
  ```
- Or you want `bar` to inherit from a specific instantiation of `foo` such as :

  ```
  class bar : public foo<int>
  {
  public:
      bar(int a):foo(a){}
  };


  int main()
  {
      bar obj(10);
  }
  ```

Comment: From the first code, `T` in `foo<T>` say that `bar` template parameter is also a `foo` template parameter. Am I correct ?

Comment: @Mahesh yes, `bar<int>` inherits from `foo<int>`